# Azure Active Directory Server 2016 Group Policy Startup Applications (Chrome) not loading on client workstations

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016, entra-id

Hi I'm trying to implement a Group Policy in our domain that forces Google Chrome to be added to client startup applications. I've added a GPO and added the key:

```
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Logon > Run These Programs at User Logon
```

In the "Items to run at logon"  I've added the path to chrome.exe (with quotes) like so:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

I've then linked to the Object in our Domain's User and Computer OUs.

I've also pushed the update out to clients and confirmed they have updated GP.

However Chrome does not start when users boot into their laptops.

I'm hoping someone can shine a light on what I've done wrong/what I've forgotten to do - any help much appreciated!

Comment: That is a bad idea because Chrome would run as `Local System` if you do it this way. A better approach would be to e.g. put a shortcut to the startup folder.

Comment: I understand however there are other apps we want to add to startup apps for users so figuring out how we can do it would be of use :) There's something clearly wrong with my approach I'm just wondering what it is/how I should do it correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per duenni1's comment it looks like the most successful way people are reporting is to use the startup folder instead of the logon group policy. 
"In my opinion the correct solution: use GPP to manage shortcuts in startup menu folder. Simply create a startup shortcuts."

"Could throw it in this directory:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

This will launch the program when they login, we do this to force users into our IM client﻿"

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1369848-run-these-programs-at-user-logon

If you really want this method to work, I'd start troubleshooting here:

1) is there already a GPO in place that will perform Run These Programs at user logon? That may be the winning GPO

[GPO Run these programs at user logon not taking effect](https://serverfault.com/questions/573713/gpo-run-these-programs-at-user-logon-not-taking-effect?rq=1)

http://woshub.com/diagnose-group-policies-issues-with-gpresult/

2) According to the official docs, no error is a path issue ( I think your usage of quotes is correct but out of curiosity I'd be curious if removing the quotes has a change).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/240791/how-to-run-programs-automatically-when-a-user-logs-on

```
NOTE: If the program does not run, make sure the path is correct. The program does not run (and no error message is displayed) if the path is not found.
```

Comment: Brilliant stuff thank you very much - I had tried without the quotation marks initially and added them after it didn't work. It seems to be working now, 24 hours later!

Comment: Happy to help! :)